# Mysql not ignoring columns that are not in my SQL query

Tags: mysql, linux

I am migrating from Windows to manjaro linux, everything is fine, but when I try to insert data using a SQL query, it's not ignoring the columns that are not in query but in the table.

Let's say I have a table that stores terms. I have columns

```
id, term_name, term_type, icon, sort_id
```

In Windows if I use a query like this:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO terms (term_name, term_type) VALUES ('some_name', 'category')";
```

`$query1` works fine in Windows.

When I use `$query1` in linux manjaro, it does not work but throws an error

> Field icon has no default value

On my hostgator hosting, `$query1` works fine with no errors in logs.

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO terms (term_name, term_type, icon, sort_id) VALUES ('some_name', 'category', 'some_icon.png', 0)";
```

`$query2` query works in linux manjaro. But now I cannot update so many queries to be as much absolute like this.

Comment: *"field icon has no default value"* that error is NOT platform depended query1 should fail on window and linux based MySQL Servers.. Most likely the linux system has icon `NOT NULL` defined in the table structure where the windows system table does not have `NOT NULL` and allowes the missing icon value..

Comment: $query1 is working in windows and working in linux hosting.
but not working in manjaro i installed in my pc.
i checked every table structure with phpmyadmin in both hosting and manjaro every coloumn has null value no and default value none

Comment: wierd MySQL execution should not magically change on manjaro which is linux.. Unless manjaro misses a few C/C++ API's which MySQL might need but still MySQL should not work then..

Comment: if it need c++ api(s) it must be listed as dependencies, i used pacman to install it. isn't it supposed to throw a warning or something for missing dependencies but it did not.
i am suspecting with my little experience is, everything is preconfigured in xampp but i had to configure everything while installing manually.
so is there is some settings in php or some module or setting in mysql.conf i missed ?

Comment: Well focus on **"wierd MySQL execution should not magically change on manjaro which is linux.."** And also *" i checked every table structure with phpmyadmin in both hosting and manjaro every coloumn has null value no and default value none"* You sure you checked it correctly and not checked the wrong browser tab for example, MySQL does not give a *"invalid"* error *"field icon has no default value"* because computers/software do not make mistakes, poeple make those..  Annyhow `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` ..

Comment: these are the list of php extenstion enabled in my installation.

bz2
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

Comment: *"these are the list of php extenstion enabled in my installation"* active PHP modules/extensions will not change MySQL execution., check mine other comment aswell, i updated/editted it we need to see the table structures -> `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`

Comment: Array
(
    [Table] => users_token
    [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `users_token` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valid_till` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=120 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32
)

Comment: this is what i got from show create table users_token

Comment: *"this is what i got from show create table users_token"* wrong table?  You insert into table `terms` ?  Atleast that is in the question..

Comment: no the same behaviour is happening in each query and for each table, it's not ignoring coloumns value i am not inserting. anyway i am showing terms table too

Comment: Array
(
    [Table] => terms
    [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `terms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `term_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `term_group` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
)

Comment: well iam out of the question as it takes way to much time to debug wrong/invalid/contradictory information...Looking into the CREATE TABLE statement there is no `icon` column

Comment: i have written example db structure , i am asking about behaviour which is happening for the whole db.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already created the table, you can use `ALTER` to set default values.
The syntax varies across DBs:

For MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ALTER columnname SET DEFAULT 'value';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why no one could figure out what was the problem in this case.
Anyways I solved my problem, it was a problem with `SQL` *strict mode*.
I edited the config with `sql_mode = ""` and now queries are working.
I will look into strict mode in detail later.